# How to write migration create table with options (DISTRIBUTE BY HASH(id)) for Sequel / Ruby

Tags: ruby, sequel

**How to write migration create table with options like DISTRIBUTE BY HASH(id) for Sequel**

Example in Ruby

```
create_table(:table_name) do
  primary_key :id
  column :column_name, :text
end
```

Вesired result in SQL

```
CREATE TABLE "table_name" (
  "id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
  "column_name" text,
) DISTRIBUTE BY HASH(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sequel doesn't have code that generates that SQL, so you need to use `run`:

```
run(<<END)
CREATE TABLE "table_name" (
  "id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
  "column_name" text,
) DISTRIBUTE BY HASH(id);
END
```

Comment: Yes, I looked at the source code and did not see that it was possible to implement this, thanks J.E. maybe you do this functionality :-)